# Dojo resize with percentage

Tags: javascript, dojo

How do I do this - dojo is fine with this:

```
thisB.resize({w: 20});
```

but i want:

```
thisB.resize({w: 20%});
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be better to use dojo/dom-style to do any resizing of widgets or elements:

```
// For a div
domStyle.set(myDiv, { width: "50%" });

// For a widget
domStyle.set(myButton.domNode, { width: "20px" });
```

Or you could try putting the percentage values in quotes in you example above like:

```
thisB.resize({w: "20%"});
```

More info about domStyle can be found [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/dom-style.html).

Comment: i get this:Uncaught TypeError: Object #<MouseEvent> has no method 'set'

Comment: Could you specify what thisB is.  Is it a dojo widget?  Could you post a code snippet?